# Is there a word to describe "the thing that makes an intersection"?

Tags: verbs

Is there a word to describe "the thing that makes an intersection"?

For example, the thing that drive is the driver, the thing that eats is the eater, and the thing that intersects is what? The intersector? The intersecter?

Comment: When two intersecting roads create an intersection, *intersecting road* already describes the thing just fine, and no further noun is needed.

Comment: Ok, but I am asking about a noun to name a class(programing language) that computes the intersections between one or more groups.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about choosing names for something in a programming context.

Comment: *connexion*: a relation between things or events (as in the case of one causing the other or sharing features with it)

Comment: The cross street.

Comment: I assume "civil contractor" or "road builder" is not on your radar :-)

Comment: @tchrist, why off-topic? Here is not the right place to ask something related to the English language if it has a context?

Comment: @nohros Choosing names for program thingies is always off-topic here.

Comment: @tchrist If a have the same question for other purposes it will be off-topic too?

Comment: @nohros If you can get rid of the references to choosing names for program thingies, it can be on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately "intersector" isn't a word in English.

Here is the first definition of "intersect" from Dictionary.com:

> to cut or divide by passing through or across: "The highway intersects the town."

If you're intending this particular definition, then intersect is synonymous with divide, and the word you are looking for is **divider**.

Here is the second definition:

> to cross, as lines or wires.

This is the meaning of "intersect" that applies to two roads that cross each other. The point where two roads intersect is called an intersection.

If you're thinking of this definition, then it doesn't really make sense to speak of a single "intersector."

But I think the term you're really looking for is **intersection**, as it is used in set theory and Venn diagrams. See the Wikipedia article on set theory here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory

Comment: The context of the world that I'm looking for is the one that is used in the set theory, but I'm not looking for the **intersection** term, but a term the describes the thing that computes the **intersection**.

Comment: Oh, okay Nohros. There's no rule that class names in an object-oriented programming language have to be real words. Maybe you could use something like IntersectionDeterminer?